# Write program to find and replace the character in the word

Tags: c, string, pointers

Program question is:
Write a C program to find and replace the character in the word.
Here flag('A'/'F') indicates whether all occurrences has to be replaced or only the first occurrence has to be replaced.

I have written this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void cond(char *a,int n,char k,char l,char m)
{
    printf("The word is\n");
    int i,count=0,max=0;
    switch(m)
    {
        case 'A':
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==k)
            {
                a[i]=l;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==0)
        {
            printf("No such character present in the word.");
        }
        else
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",a[i]);
        }
        break;
        case 'F':
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            while(max<1)
            {
                if(a[i]==k)
                {
                    a[i]=l;
                    max++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(max==0)
        {
            printf("No such character present in the word.");
        }
        else
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",a[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char a[20],b,e,p;
    printf("Enter the word:\n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("Enter the character to be find:\n");
    scanf("%c\n",&b);
    printf("Enter the character to be replaced:\n");
    scanf("%c\n",&e);
    printf("Enter the 'A'/'F':\n");
    scanf("%c\n",&p);
    int n=strlen(a);
    cond(a,n,b,e,p);
    return 0;
}
```

It does not give any output

For example:
If I input this
Enter the word: aeroplane
Enter the character to be find:a 
Enter the character to be replaced:z 
Enter the 'A'/'F': A
The word is

It gives a blank output

someone, please help me for this code.

Comment: 0) `scanf("%c\n",&b);` --> `scanf(" %c", &b);` and so on.

Comment: Basically, you should not change the code listed in the question. It loses consistency.

Comment: Sorry sir, i will not change now but by replacing this scanf("%c\n",&b); with scanf(" %c",&b); I am unable to enter the inputs

Comment: Do you assume white-spaces character as corresponding(find and replaced) character?

Comment: That seems a ton of code for conditional character replacement. It should be doable in about two lines of code using a crafty `for` loop, a pointer, and [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr). I'd read up on that function. It would be *very* handy for solving this problem.

Comment: [one solution](http://ideone.com/GtiApd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `a` is of type `char*`, `a[i]` is a `char`. `k` is a `char` too, thus you can simply compare them like this:

```
if(a[i] == k)
```

---

Moreover your scnafs' use the newline, discard it. Change this:

```
scanf("%c\n",&b);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %c",&b);
```

where you should notice I left a space before `%c`, in order to eat a pending character (I have an example [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/)).

Comment: @Riturajkumar then your logic is flawed.

Comment: then can u please give a proper solution of this.

Comment: by replacing this scanf("%c\n",&b); with scanf(" %c",&b); I am unable to enter the inputs

Answer (score 0):

1. If you test your functions it is better to create some test cases and avoid user input. This can be added later when you are sure that your function works.
2. Example (I do not know what `n` means in your example as you even do not declare it in your main :)

   ```
   int s_replace(char *haystack, char needle, char replace, char flag)  // a/A only first - any other complete
   {
   int result = 0;

   if (haystack == NULL) result = -1;

   if (!result)
   {
       while (*haystack)
       {
           if (*haystack == needle)
           {
               *haystack = replace;

               if (!(result++) && tolower(flag) == 'a')
               {
                   break;
               }
           }
           haystack++;
       }
   }
   return result;
   }

    int main()
   {
   int result;
   char test[] = "Program question is: Write a C program to find and replace the character in the word. Here flag('A'/'F') indicates whether all occurrences has to be replaced or only the first occurrence has to be replaced.";

   printf("Original string = \"%s\"\n", test);
   result = s_replace(test, 'a', 'z', 'A');
   switch (result)
   {
   case -1:
       printf("Error !!!!!\n");
       break;
   case 0:
       printf("Nothing was found. \n");
       break;
   default:
       printf("Amended  string = \"%s\"\n", test);
       printf("Number of changes - %d\n", result);
   }

   return 0;
   }
   ```